# Daemonize Django Management Command

Tags: django, sockets, daemon, celery

I'm trying to create a socket application that listen for incoming emails in port 25 using python's smptd and asyncore library, the app should have access to Django ORM to take the necessary actions.

The way I did so far is creating a python script that access Django database directly, and run it under supervisor but it wasn't a nice solution. The appropriate one would be having a management command or something like a task queue (Celery).

If I create a Django management command to run this long running socket application, can I just attach it to supervisor? Do I need to daemonize it? What is the difference and how can I daemonize it? I've found django.utils.daemonize but didn't find any documentation about it.

Will it be more appropriate to solve it with Celery?. My application listens to a socket, while Celery, in my understanding, waiting for a trigger, I haven't find any sample of a long running task in Celery that is automatically started when celeryd is launched.

Answer (score 3):

For your task using python + [supervisord](http://supervisord.org) is the best solution I think. Because the goal of Celery is executing tasks, and run scheduled tasks.
There are exit way when your scripts will create tasks for Celery, it will provide better perfomance. But you should use celery only when you need to run scheduled background tasks, or you have long-executing tasks in your daemon.

Comment: Exactly. Supervisord is just the best thing for a manage.py command like

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate solution to management commands, I suggest that you have your email server call a web service provided by Django.

This has a couple of benefits

- the mailserver is de-coupled from Django, so you can put them on different servers if you want
- the only daemon you need is for the mail program
- no celery required -- Django doesn't need to care about any triggering, because the Django component is passive